# LogicApp that returns newly generated ID back to original source

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dynamics-crm, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

Hello I am trying to create a **LogicApp** that first:

1. **Extracts data from CosmosDB**, using a query
2. **Loops over the results**
3. **Pushes the results data into CRM**

*Sidenote: Once this data is pushed into CRM, **CRM automatically generates an ID** for each record. How can I then:*

4. My biggest dilemma is figuring out ***how can I return the newly generated ID back to the original CosmosDB container in  which it was pulled from?***

I have started on this and these are my questions:

Does this first part look correct in what I am doing? I must use this SQL query for this:

a. I am simply telling the Logic App to extract data from a particular container inside CosmosDB

[image]

b. Then I would like to loop over the results I just obtained, and push this to CRM

[image]

c. My **dilemma** is:

*Once data is pushed to CRM, CRM then automatically generates an ID for each record that is uploaded*. **How would I then return the updated ID to cosmos?**

*Should I create a variable that stores the IDS, then replace the old IDs with the new ones?*

I am not sure how to construct/write this logic within LogicApps and have been researching examples of this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this the same exact question you asked yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082347/logic-app-to-push-data-from-cosmosdb-into-crm-and-perform-an-update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logic App to push data from Cosmosdb into CRM and perform an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082347/logic-app-to-push-data-from-cosmosdb-into-crm-and-perform-an-update)

Comment: Hi @MarkBrown, it is similar, but I am moreso specifically asking how I can return updated IDs to CosmosDB once they have been generated by the CRM (whilst using LogicApps)

Answer (score 1):

If the call to your CRM system returns the ID you are talking about then I would just add one additional action in your loop  in Azure Logic App to update the read record in Azure Cosmos DB. Given that you are doing a `SELECT *` from the container you should have the whole original document.

Add the 'Create or update document' action as a step with a reference to the `THFeature` container along with your `Database ID` and then provide the new values for the document. I pasted an example below.

[image]

BTW. Your select query looks strange - you should avoid slow cross partition queries if you can.

Comment: Thank you a Martin! This may work! 
I am pulling from a small set this is why I am using this particular SELECT statement. ‘Slow cross partition query’ meaning it’s not time efficient?

Comment: If it is a small dataset then it will not impact much but when it starts to grow you want to avoid cross partition queries which effectively scans all your data. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.